# Windows Performance Monitor "Sample interval" vs. Alert interval

Tags: windows-server-2012, performance-monitoring, scheduled-task

I want to get an alert via email whenever available memory drops below a certain threshold on my Windows Server 2012

To do this, I'm using a User-Defined Performance Monitor Data Collector Set. I've configured a Data Collector with a performance counter and alert criteria. I've set up the Alert Task (and the task is set up in Task Scheduler). All that works fine, and I am getting the alerts by email.

My question is about the Data Collector sample interval. I've set that up at, say 60 seconds, because I want to check for low memory every minute. BUT, I don't want an alert every 60 seconds (I rather have one every 15 minutes.)

Is there any way to have an alert interval that different from the sample interval?

Comment: So, just for clarity, you want it to send you an alert the first instance that the memory threshold is reached, but not send another email for at least 15 minutes for the same issue?

Comment: @austinian Correct

Comment: Awesome. That was the assumption I was operating under when I wrote my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would set up the Action of the task to "Start a Program" instead of "Send an e-mail". The program to start would be a Powershell script that does this: check the time of the last alert sent, and if the last alert was more than 15 minutes ago, send a new alert using [Send-MailMessage](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Hh849925.aspx) and update the last alert time. You can store the last alert time in a helper file next to the script or somewhere else.

Example script:

```
$timeFile = "[PATH TO TIME FILE]"
$needNewAlert = true

if (Test-Path $timeFile -PathType Leaf) {
    $starttime = [datetime](Get-Content $timeFile)
    $timespan = New-TimeSpan -Start $starttime -End (Get-Date -Format u)
    if ($timespan.TotalMinutes -lt 15.0) {
        $needNewAlert = false
    }
}

if ($needNewAlert) {
    Send-MailMessage -From server@example.com -To me@example.com -Subject "I'm in too deep!"
    Get-Date -Format u > $timeFile
}
```

As an aside: you can further reduce the number of alert emails from a given system by using one script for multiple triggers by passing arguments/flags into the script to indicate the source of the issue. You'll have to keep track of the last alert time on a per issue basis (one way to do this are to keep the source/timestamp pairs in a dictionary/hash table and save the object to a file using [Export-CliXML](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Hh849916.aspx) and load the object with [Import-CliXML](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Hh849906.aspx)), then you can have the body of the email be a summary of all current issues reported in this manner.

Comment: Thanks. I was already using a PS script and Send-MailMessage, so your change was an easy fix. Of course, I'd rather have a way to tell PerfMon to handle this (and avoid starting a process for nothing), but this will do.

Comment: That'd have to be filed away as a feature request to Microsoft! As it stands, I don't think that this will happen, especially since they've deprecated the "Send an e-mail" and "Display a message" options, at least as of Windows 10.